# adding extension exclusion to listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have some code where i am taking the value of a `TextBox` and using it as `io.directoryInfo`. It takes the info provided and add it to a listbox. Along with what the base folder name is. I would like to limit this to only accept .avi, .mp4, and .wmv filetypes. Can someone help?

```
Private Sub ButtonOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOk.Click

    Dim BaseFolder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBoxFolderLocation.Text)
    For Each f As IO.DirectoryInfo In BaseFolder.GetDirectories()
        AddContents(f)
    Next
End Sub

Sub AddContents(ByVal BaseFolder As IO.DirectoryInfo)
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange((From FI As IO.FileInfo In BaseFolder.GetFiles Select FI.Name).ToArray)
    For Each subF As IO.DirectoryInfo In BaseFolder.GetDirectories()
        Application.DoEvents()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("[" & BaseFolder.Name & "]")
        AddContents(subF)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The `GetFiles` method let's you specify a pattern that file names must match, so you can filter by extension that way.  It only let's you specify one pattern, so if you want to match multiple then you have to call `GetFiles` multiple times and combine the results.

Comment: By the way, there are times where function syntax is more succinct that query syntax. I'd suggest replacing `From FI As IO.FileInfo In BaseFolder.GetFiles Select FI.Name` with `BaseFolder.GetFiles().Select(Function(FI) FI.Name)`. They are functionally equivalent though, so the first is just as valid if you prefer it.

Comment: Thank You 3vts. I understand the use of .GetFiles(). But i am having some trouble implementing it into this example above. Could i possibly talk you into giving me an reference on how you would use it?